# It may rain today.

Tags: logic

Is the above statement true? Because whether or not it rains, the presence of "may" in the statement prevents it from being false if it does not rain; ofcourse true otherwise.

Or is it even a statement?

Comment: The reson why I asked this is that I am struck upon judging whether "The power set may be denumerable" is true or false. Although it can never be, and the statement already covers this part, I guess. It is just searching if there is any possibility.

Comment: The statement is logically false if it is impossible to have rain today.

Answer (score 2):

It says that there is a non-zero possibility of rain today, the truth of which depends on the circumstances (and you also need to specify exactly where ... and what counts as 'rain': a single drop? Some 'mist'?)

Of course, that is looking at the statement from a purely logical point of view!

In a real life use of that sentence, we typically mean something like 'there is a decent (though not great) chance that it will rain' ... think 10-20% or so, where by 'rain' we mean 'typical rain' ... whatever that means ... more than a single drop though ... enough of it that you indeed would like to know about it and maybe bring your umbreally :)

Comment: It is a mathematical statement then. Right?

Comment: that's not how people use it, in vernacular it means *there is a small chance of rain today*

Comment: This answer is not what "it may rain today" means. It means that it will rain today with probability strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Good point! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), which treats such statements formally. This statement basically says "it is possible that it will rain", which would be contradicted if rain were somehow impossible that day. Whether rain is possible at a given place on a given day is perhaps a complicated question of meteorology.

Answer (score 0):

"The power set *may* be denumerable" (from your comment) is not a logical statement. It is a comment. The author is emphasizing that his claim or proposition does not depend on the power set in question being uncountable.